# Is it possible to run google maps navigation in IOS instead apple maps

Tags: ios, google-maps, ios6, google-maps-sdk-ios, apple-maps

In my app I have used my app to run Apple maps application and pass it start and end coordinates so user can be navigated.
Is there any option to use the same but with google maps.
Does it require app download or something like that?
Is there any example how to use google for navigation from location to location?

Comment: Does [this link](http://maniacdev.com/2012/10/example-project-showing-how-to-use-google-maps-in-ios-6-using-map-kit) help you?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use **Google URL Scheme** for **navigation from location to location**. The documentation is great, but you must validate if the google maps App exist on the user iPhone.

**OPTION 1 :**

Example :

```
If user have iOS 5 and older, use Google URL Scheme,
If user have iOS 6 and google maps installed, use Google URL Scheme
If user have iOS 6 and google maps not installed, use Apple maps URL scheme
```

[Google URL Scheme documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/urlscheme)

*Attention, when using Google URL Scheme, your application switch to Google Maps app.*

**OPTION 2 :**

> Is there any option to use the same but with google maps

[Google Maps for iOS SDK](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/?hl=fr)

> Does it require app download or something like that?

Yes, Google Maps SDK for iOS

Answer (score 0):

iOS >= 6.0 is using Apple maps, while when < 6.0 uses Google maps. If you want to show Google maps in all cases, put a webview and utilise Google web maps.